# TeamCity: Copy a remote file back to the build agent so it can be published as an artifact

Tags: teamcity

So due to some specific limitations with the build environment and our TeamCity agents, we have a build in TeamCity that runs remote commands via ssh exec to build an exe file on a separate server that is not a TeamCity agent. That all works perfectly.

The problem is, I'd really like to publish that built exe as an artifact within TeamCity, but I'm unable to because it's not on the actual build agent.

Does TeamCity have an easy way for the build agent to grab a remote file, maybe via ssh, and copy it into the build directory? I feel like that should exist but I don't see anything here.